# Go back to my last search page

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

We need a feature where we find a link or a button in the question page leading to the last visited page in the questions page.

Because now when the user go to a certain question, ask a question, answer or comment it and want to go back to the page he was on, this will be hard.

I see rent a coder doing this in bid request page
[image]

Comment: Your browser's back button?

Comment: Yes, but for example if you asked a question and tried to press back it will lead you to editing the question

Comment: Press it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a great feature for those who fall into any one of the following:

- No browser back button
- No <kbd>ALT</kbd> and/or <kbd>⟵</kbd> keys or even the <kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd> key
- For Opera users (or those on Firefox using the utterly down boot wannabe plugin for mouse gestures) without a left and right mouse button combo.