# Will Meta Stack Exchange be merged with Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta

Will Meta Stack Exchange be merged with Meta Stack Overflow?  Would such a merge be a good idea?  A bad one?

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer changing jurisdiction as commented [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6392/mse-merging-with-mso/6393#6393), i.e. make things more consistent and less history burdened:

- meta.SO: meta questions concerning SO like retag requests etc., just like the beta-metas now
- meta.SE: everything concerning the SE framework itself.

The only consistent alternative (IMHO) would be merging *all* meta sites into one, also solving the "bug reports belong on meta.SO" issues at the beta-metas at the moment. And tagging might prevent cluttering...

Answer (score 2):

Doubtful at this point.

meta.se is a support site for SE 1.0.

Maybe once all the SE 1.0 sites (except for the tiny handful of "protected" ones) are decommissioned, we can do something different.

edit: we decided to make this change, as the # of living, legacy SE 1.0 sites has dwindled to a fairly small number.

Comment: did you have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com recently? Almost all questions are about SE-2.0 in fact. And even worse, spam occurs and is not flagged into oblivion after a mere two days. Didn't you mention broken windows should be avoided?

Comment: And, while you're at it, @Jeff, do look at the meta.SE FAQ.  It doesn't mention SE 1.0 at any point, so how are people supposed to *know*?

Comment: So why doesn't MSE replace MSO and let MSO become the per-site meta of SO?

Comment: @ivo why doesn't England use the Euro? Sometimes there are political and time reasons..