# Are meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow "one and the same"?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta, site-crossover, dns

This seems counterintuitive to the vertical nature of Stack Exchange itself, but I cannot manage to browse to `meta.stackexchange.com`: I get redirected to `meta.stackoverflow.com`, instead.

This is also despite the fact that these URLs resolve to separate IP addresses...

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> meta.stackexchange.com
meta.stackexchange.com. 3421    IN  A   64.34.80.165

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> meta.stackoverflow.com
meta.stackoverflow.com. 684 IN  A   64.34.119.12
```

Am I being dumb somehow, or is this *"the way it is"*? If so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they're the same.

MSO was the first meta site to be introduced, before the per-site metas, and now functions as both the meta for SO, and as a sort of über-meta for the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 12):

At the moment, yes, MSE points to MSO. MSE used to be the support site for Stack Exchange 1.0 sites, but enough of those have been shut down that it [no longer needed to exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57265/will-meta-stack-exchange-be-merged-with-meta-stack-overflow/57377#57377). Meanwhile, as Stack Exchange evolved, MSO became the meta-site for the whole network ([longer version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96313/why-is-stack-overflows-meta-also-the-meta-of-the-whole-stack-exchange-engine)). Jeff has said that [it's only a matter of time before MSO gets renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).