# Is there a common meta for all stackexchange websites?

Tags: support

I wanted a ask a question related to editing of videos (how to fade out audio and video in a scene). There are stacks like `movies.stackexchange.com` but they discuss movies at that stack.

Is there a meta where users can ask: which is the best stack discuss arbitrary questions like `What is the foo way to do foo?` My question is intentionally double nested.

P.S. I assume this meta is related to programming questions only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is. This is the original (And official) meta for SE behavior.

Comment: Note, however, that it is planned to get a meta.SE that would take over that role and make this one the meta for Stack Overflow, as its name suggests. That will take [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/177145).

Comment: Original? I'm pretty sure there *used* to be a Meta SE, which became Meta SO, and is soon to be split into Meta SE and Meta SO. I wouldn't say it's really the original. :P

Comment: @animuson: Really? I always thought that SO (and meta SO) came first, then SE, then the rest of the sites and their metas, so usability, bahvior, and general problems were originally on this meta.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57265) suggests that there once were separate Meta SO and Meta SE sites, and they were merged. Sounds about right. I can't find the question which is linked in the answer...

Answer (score 3):

You are asking your question on the network meta, Meta Stack Overflow. From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange
> - Stack Overflow Careers
> - Promotions & Advertising
> - Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites
>
> ... it is welcome here.

Each Stack Exchange site has it's own FAQ; it's a good idea to "lurk" on the site and take a look at other questions to get a feel for what's on-topic, as well as looking at the FAQ, of course. :)

Note that Stack Overflow is specifically listed in the FAQ. When the sites were originally created, Meta Stack Overflow was the *only* meta for the 3 trilogy sites, Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User. They all now have their own per-site metas, but Stack Overflow continues to use this one. However, see [Daniel's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148905/is-there-a-common-meta-for-all-stackexchange-websites/148909#comment428116_148906) as there are plans to separate Meta Stack Overflow and create a "Meta Stack Exchange".

Comment: Read Daniels comment. This meta leads to a medley of questions which belong to very separate categories. A separate meta common to all SEs sounds good.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying @ShashankSawant, this is currently the Meta for *all* Stack Exchange sites, even though it's called "Meta Stack Overflow", and there is a plan in the works currently to separate Stack Overflow's meta from the meta for all Stack Exchange sites, so that Stack Overflow would then have it's own, separate meta, separated from the network meta.