# Stack Overflow Help Center is wrong about Meta account and reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, help-center

I found this gem in the  [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) subpage of Help Center:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

The whole section is actually wrong for this very meta site:

> [image]

According to this post [Merging meta reputation to SO reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149657/merging-meta-reputation-to-so-reputation) That is not correct because meta SO provides a little bit for all Stack Exchange.

It sounds like an old feature but the about page was never updated..

Comment: @Bart: read the title? It's on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta (I'm pretty sure even the section title "If you have an account on Stack Overflow, you have an account on its meta site." is a blatant lie.)

Comment: On the *Stack Overflow* help center. There's a link at the bottom "What is "meta"? How does it work?"

Comment: @Wooble Gotcha. Updated the post with the link. And yeah, network-wide copy-pasta I'd say.

Comment: How does this hidden under the rug? In the about page of all places. *If you have an account on Stack Overflow, you have an account on its meta site.* in title font.

Comment: The reason is pretty obvious: the help center pages are the same all over the network and that section is correct for all sites except Stack Overflow, having unique Meta site with different rules. I was sure it was reported before but couldn't find the dupe.

Comment: *a blatant lie*, really or did I miss the sarcasm, @Wooble?

Comment: @Arjan: I'm nearly certain having an account on SO doesn't automatically create an MSO account, so...

Comment: Sure, @Wooble, but calling that *a [blatant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blatant) lie* seems quite over the top, to me. But that's just a detail.

Comment: @Arjan The actual meta help center [whats-meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) says this: *On Meta Stack Overflow, everyone must create a separate account.*

Comment: I'm talking about the "blatant" part, TsSkTo. But well.

Comment: "may post"? Clearly that is not only until users gain 5 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow's help page has been updated to include the same text that appears on the Meta Stack Overflow page, which correctly states that accounts on MSO work differently than meta accounts on the rest of the network.

Comment: Looks like the split messed things up again. [New bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272013/whats-meta-text-doesnt-make-sense-for-this-site).