# "whats-meta" text doesn't make sense for this site

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, help-center

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

> If you have an account on Meta Stack Exchange, you have an account on
>   its meta site.
>
> You do not need to create a separate account for meta; once you are
>   logged in on Meta Stack Exchange, you are also logged in and may post
>   on its meta site.
>
> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is
>   the same as your reputation on Meta Stack Exchange (synchronized
>   hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation
>   to participate on meta.

Meta SE doesn't have a meta site!

Comment: Shh! Don't tell anyone but it's the super secret http://meta.meta.stackexchange,com ;)

Comment: [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194944/stack-overflow-help-center-is-wrong-about-meta-account-and-reputation), but since it's wrongly marked status-completed,  not closing yet

Comment: @ChrisF I get a DNS error if I try to visit that URL  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Ah it's the comma in place of the dot. Nope, still DNS error  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Thanks. I searched for ["whats-meta"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22whats-meta%22) and didn't find that. I agree it's not fixed though.

Comment: Well, it was fixed for a short while until the MSO/MSE split. I think.

Comment: Bah, considering how late this question is asked, we can get statistics in how many people actually read the help center stuff. ;)

Comment: @kos Here, you forgot this: `\ ` and this: `\ `

Comment: @CodingWithClass Yeah, fair enough. Markdown ate them. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've removed that whole section from Meta Stack Exchange's help center. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: While you're at it, I think [this whole section about "How to not be a spammer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) is also not relevant for MSE, or any meta site. Maybe more sections are not relevant, didn't go through all of them yet. :)

Comment: While it's true that we never, ever ever get spam here on MSE, I think customizing that page for hundreds of sites is more work than it's worth, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @Shog9 the spam we get here is not self promotion inside otherwise legit answer, which is what the help section is about... and I assumed there's some template for meta sites? If not, and someone need to customize them one by one then it's really not worth such efforts.