# reopen-questions help center article: "community's meta site"?

Tags: feature-request, meta, help-center, vote-to-reopen

In https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions, it is mentioned:

> If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site. Asking in the meta site allows those who took the action to comment, and will help others to learn about the issues being discussed. You can find a link to a site's meta in the two place in every site's top bar: under the "help" menu in the upper right, and in the Stack Exchange site switcher in the upper left.

Let's say that a question has been closed in Meta Stack Exchange and the OP is *unsure about the validity of the closure*. The OP read the aforementioned help center article and will start wondering what is the meta site of Meta Stack Exchange.

AFAIK, there is no meta site of Meta Stack Exchange.

I request someone to change the help center article content to something more appropriate.

Comment: Related [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272013/289691), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302510/289691)

Comment: What do you think will be a more appropriate way to point users to Meta SE?

Comment: @Rubén I am sorry. I didn't get you. Can you please be more clearer?

Comment: Your request could be more specific. Instead of just asking to apply a change " to something more appropriate" you could include a suggestion of how the change might look.

Comment: @Rubén I am quite new to MSE and I am not quite sure about what would be a good suggestion. So far, Spevacus' suggestion about posting in MSE using [tag:meta] tag and [tag:reopen-closed] tag sounds good :)

Comment: Considering the answer is "we're not going to customize it" there might not be worthy to spend more time improving this specific question. Related to how to make a good feature request [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98739/289691), [b](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189/289691)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, like most help center articles, is the same network-wide. We simply don't have an easy way to branch it that allows us to update it once network wide. This is why we don't generally allow sites to customize these pages, either. We'd end up with dozens of pages that would either never get updated information or that we'd be overriding and removing important information every time we need to change the content of the page. So we don't customize it.

We expect that there will be slight differences in a tiny subset of cases. In this case, it doesn't perfectly make sense on MSE or Stack Apps - sites that are their own meta sites. So, no, we're not going to customize it. If we need to update this page in six months, customizing any pages that reference a child meta would become immediately outdated.

Answer (score 2):

While this site's help center could use a bit of an update on this matter, I feel that it's important to point out that we have a tag for asking questions about *this* site. It's the [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag.

You can use this tag in combination with others, for example, [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed), if you were inquiring as to getting a closed question on *this* site reopened. Here's a [relatively recent example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343995/622284) of this in action.

Typically, you should only ask questions about getting a specific question reopened on this site if you've exhausted the typical routes: Editing your question so that it's more likely to be reopened, and letting the reopen review queue item that was created as a result of that edit to receive an outcome.

Comment: "recent example"...  post is 1 year ago 

Comment: @RandomPerson I did say "relatively" recent! We don't get a lot of closed questions that are brought up this way here ([three times, ever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-closed+meta)). The typical routes I outlined work really well, and in cases where they don't, the mods here are quite capable of reaching an amenable resolution.